# Django website is loading slow on Heroku, it is not because of QuerySets

Tags: django, performance, heroku, pagespeed, heroku-postgres

Have website that is running on simple generic Class-Based Views. First I thought - the QuerySets are the issue but since all my queries are lower than 8ms, that is not the issue. Locally the website is running fast under - 200/300ms with all images and everything. When I have pushed it to Heroku it was slow. In the inspect chrome bar - it shows 1 straight line for 1-2 seconds and then loading the rest - it waits 1-2 seconds and then it loads. So I have started to break down the process and came to 1 conclusion - removed the DB and it started loading very fast like 100ms - when I have plugged in the Postgres DB - instantly went to slow mode.

Have installed `Django-Toolbar` as well to see what is going on.

`Note: this is not a question about the load time when the dyno is sleeping. It is a question about every single refresh, request while browsing the site - the experience.`

Here are the results. I have even tried to put DB and app on higher tiers just to see and no difference. So what I did is as well created simple view Test - with 3 images that I see the images are not causing it and load it - takes 1-2secs to start loading as well - removing DB - loads very fast.

Then I came across this:
[Persistent Connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#persistent-connections)

If I set to 500 - it loads longer - setting to `None` - little faster - but having always not closed DB connections is not good. And there is no reason why small site would load that slow without that setting.

I have even tried to put it on Digital Ocean on 18.04 Ubuntu - and installed Postgres - it was little faster there but similar result. No sure what should I do more.

views.py - all views are very simple, no complex logic, mostly they do not even have `get_context_data` method.

```
class DocumentaryFullDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Documentary
    template_name = "documentary-full.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['all_documentary_photos'] = Photo.objects.filter(documentary=self.get_object()).prefetch_related('documentary')
        return context
```

Dependencies:

```
bleach==3.1.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.9.130
botocore==1.12.130
Collectfast==0.6.2
coverage==4.5.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.2.3
django-admin-sortable2==0.7.2
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-bleach==0.5.3
django-boto==0.3.12
django-cacheops==4.1
django-ckeditor==5.6.1
django-compressor==2.2
django-debug-toolbar==2.0
django-environ==0.4.5
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
django-markdownx==2.0.28
django-model-utils==3.2.0
django-nocaptcha-recaptcha==0.0.20
django-redis==4.10.0
django-sendgrid-v5==0.8.0
django-storages==1.7.1
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.7.7
funcy==1.12
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
jmespath==0.9.4
Markdown==3.1
markdown2==2.3.7
mccabe==0.6.1
olefile==0.44
Pillow==6.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-http-client==3.1.0
pytz==2018.9
rcssmin==1.0.6
redis==3.2.1
rjsmin==1.0.12
s3transfer==0.2.0
sendgrid==6.0.5
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0
urllib3==1.25.3
webencodings==0.5.1
```

***Here is the straight line around 2000ms***

[image: Chrome Inspect]

[image: django-toolbar]

[image: sql querysets]

[image: dom loading]

Answer (score 0):

Establishing connections to a Postgres database can be notoriously slow. I'd suggest using a connection pooler like PgBouncer (https://pgbouncer.github.io/). You can get a buildpack for Heroku that does most of the hard work for you transparently: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer

That way your Django application creates as many connections as it needs to local sockets, as and when it needs them, and PgBouncer keeps a pool of longer-lived connections to the actual database and you only do the expensive handshake of Postgres connection creation when necessary.

Comment: Have added that buildpack but there is no difference same result - it says - `pgbouncer app detected, Using pgbouncer version: 1.8.1-heroku`, `pgbouncer done` - so it has installed correctly, but no effect.

Comment: There's a few factors that may be at play here: the initial connections for the pool are still on-demand, so the first few requests to the server will still be slow while the pool warms up. Also, if you're not using the default environment variables for your database configuration then you'll need to manually configure pgbouncer too, otherwise Django will still connect directly to the db. Finally, connection time being the problem is an assumption too - you can drop some debug statements around https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L183 to verify.

Comment: Thank you @Sam for all the info - actually you do not need to do buildpacks - heroku has it built in - need to try it - it is not working on hobby tiers - but I can scale it up and see how it is working - `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-connection-pooling`